# Jaspersoft Studio plug-in dependency problem

Tags: eclipse, installation, jaspersoft-studio

I have installed eclipse-4.16 (2020-06) on FreeBSD-12.1p10 in order to use Jaspersoft Studio with iDempiere-7.1.   iDempiere-7.1 uses **net.sf.jasperreports.engine_6.6.0.jar** as its report engine. The current Jaspersoft Studio (6.16.0) plug-in will not install due to a dependency error.

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.jaspersoft.studio.feature.feature.group
[6.16.0.final,6.16.0.final] cannot be installed in this environment because
its filter is not applicable.
```

I have learned that the latest Jaspersoft Studio that is known to work with iDempiere-7.1 is 6.5.1.  I added **https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperstudio/files/updatesite/6.5.1/** as a plug-in site and that version is indeed selected when I attempt to install Jaspersoft Studio.  But it gives the same dependency error.

How do I get Jaspersoft Studio to install?